# How to update TableView based on Switch

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my ToDoList App I have a table view in which the user can add items that he/she has to complete. When they tap on an item they created, they are sent to the detail page in which there is a switch. If the switch is toggled on, the cell should be updated and the background color for it should be red. I don't know how to access that tableviewcell from a different page though. This is what I have so far:

```
if (switchToggle.on) {

    NSLog(@"The switch is on!");

    UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item Updated" message:@"This item has been set to 'Urgent'" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];

    [myAlertView show];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"The switch is off!");
}
```

All help is appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Why can't you just update the model and using that updated value, you can configure the view.

Comment: how so? i can't use the table view cell value from another view..can I?..

Comment: How about when you go into the cell, you pass to it its index. This index represents its position in the table. Once someone presses the switch, you update an NSArray that is used to represent states of the table view cells. You update the index position in that NSArray.

Then, when you are in the table view controller, in the cellforviewatindexpath method, you load the background color of the cell based on the NSArray you updated.

Comment: that's a good idea...ill try that

Answer (score 0):

Surely you should have an array of object form which you load the information in each cell.

In the object class you should have a property like:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic, getter=isOn) BOOL on;
```

So when you access to the details view controller, you should pass this object like for example:

```
detailsViewController.myObject = myArrayOfObject[indexPath.row];
```

And so, in your controller when you switch, you can set `YES` or `NO` in that property and by a `delegate` **call a method in your previous view controller that reload the cell**.

Use delegation pattern is the right way.

But if you want, you could also do this:

When you come back, you have to reload that `tableViewCell` and so you need to save the `indexPath` before go in the `detailsViewController`. So you can save it in a variable and then when you come back to the previous view controller, in `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear`:

```
if (savedIndexPath) {
    [myTable reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[savedIndexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];
}
```

Or again you can observer the property by `KVO` and get automatically a call when the property is changed.

You have a lot of solution and design pattern to help you. See `Delegation` and `KVO (Key Value Observing)` for example.